# Store workbook password in variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the following code but it is not working:

```
    TempFilename = "NewFile.xlsm"
    CurrentPasswd = ThisWorkbook.Password
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=TempFilename
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=TempFilename, Password:=CurrentPasswd)
```

Error I'm getting is that the supplied password is incorrect and in Watch window it actually is displayed as "****"

How can i preserve the password from the currently open workbook in variable and reuse it later?

Comment: Set the protection by VBA using a variable as password. You can then re-use the same variable to lift the protection later.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, already done that, but it is a step exposing the password in cod, and i'd like to avoid setting the password in source

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do it. If you could read the password out of a file as plain text it would make the protection pretty pointless.

Comment: Its true that reading would be pointless, but since you are mandated to enter the password to open the file first then you should be able to know it...
However, it is true that for better protection it should be "hidden". My hope was that it is possible to "decrypt" it safely.

Comment: You can have the password in the code but protect access to the code with another password. Look into password protection for the VBA Project.